# Obtain all records received within last six months

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-entities

New to Linq to Entity, trying to get all records received within the last six months.  I have spent the last several hours trying to get this to work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  When I call the 'limit' variable it is being assigned the date 01/01/0001.   Any assistance would be appreciated.  It works if I comment out the 'where' clause; however, I need it to be sorted by only the last six months.

Thanks in advance.

```
 JobSeekersEntities context = new JobSeekersEntities();

 var limit = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);

        var query = from c in context.Applications
                    where c.received > limit
                    orderby c.received descending
                    select new { c.firstName, c.middleName, c.lastName, c.street, c.city, c.state, c.zip, c.position };

        var results = query.Take(25).ToList();

        applicationDataGrid.DataContext = results;
```

Comment: When you say you call the limit variable what do you mean? I copied the limit variable in some test code and it seems to be calculated just fine.

Comment: When I use the debugger and stop it.  It shows the date as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} for the Value.

Comment: Executing `var limit = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6); Console.WriteLine(limit);` it shows `01.10.2013 00:00:00` for me. Try to print out the limit variable for you. Maybe you have to clean recompile and debugged on old binaries?

Comment: If you stop it at the line "var limit = " you will get that value. You need to press F10 to step over that code then look at value, it will be correct. Have to let that line run so that limit gets assigned.

Comment: 01/01/0001 is the default value for a DateTime object. When you debug, the selected line is the **next** line to be executed. It hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: Now don't I feel like a complete newb.  Here I thought it was my date giving me the errors.  Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stop the debugger at the line "var limit = " you will get that value. You need to press F10 to step over that code then look at value, it will be correct. Have to let that line run so that limit gets assigned. Var in this case is DateTime, which is a value type so it has a default value. I could see this being misleading.